# How to hide all the div by default in Accordion type on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have taken this example from this given below site which is not working perfect in IE.
I want to hide all the div on page load but still it shows first div open in IE while its working fine in FF and other latest browsers.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

**collapsible: true** - is not working in **IE**

and below is my current site where i am using this example.

http://new.cgwealth.com/staff

Please help me out in this

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `active` Selector for the active element. Set to false to display none at start. Needs collapsible: true.

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true            
});
```